# Temperature sensors hwmon5 and hwmon6 keep swapping around. How can I consistently monitor devices?

Tags: 20.10, temperature, conky, sensors

I have a PC (Asus Transformer 3 Pro T303UA) where I am trying to monitor the temperature of various devices (using conky). But on some boot-ups `hwmon5` is the WiFi device and `hwmon6` is the CPU but on other boot-ups it's reversed (`hwmon5` is the CPU and `hwmon6` is the WiFi).

So if I setup monitoring to look at CPU cores `hwmon5 temp 2` and `hwmon5 temp 3` when `hwmon5` is the CPU that works and is correct, but if `hwmon5` changes to be the wifi device then there is no `temp 2` or `temp 3` so the monitoring fails.

**Does anyone know why this one PC seems to change it's devices around (none of my other PCs seem to do this) and if I can stop it from happening or get all the temperatures some other way which will always be consistent?**

Today `hwmon6` is the cpu:

```
ls -la /sys/class/hwmon/

hwmon0 -> ../../devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/AC0/hwmon0
hwmon1 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/hwmon1
hwmon2 -> ../../devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/hwmon2
hwmon3 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone6/hwmon3
hwmon4 -> ../../devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/hwmon/hwmon4
hwmon5 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone8/hwmon5
hwmon6 -> ../../devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From version 1.11.3 (feb 2019) of conky, you can now use the device *name* instead of a number. This searches in all the `/sys/class/hwmon/*/name` files for the name, and takes the first one that matches. So instead of `${hwmon 5 temp 2}` you might be able to use, say,

```
${hwmon coretemp temp 2}
```

if coretemp is the string in `hwmon5/name`.
Failing that, the simplest answer is to use a small script to edit your config file before starting conky as I don't think it will be easy to fix the order of discovery of these i2c devices. See also, the `lm_sensors` package that can find sensor values for you.